# Customize Material Design CSS & JS Component

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button, material-design, material-design-lite

I've been trying to find a material design **CSS & JS** framework that is able to provide a custom download of the components.

In other words, and for example with Material Design Lite, if I only need radio buttons, is there any way for me to download only the CSS and JS? What is the fastest way to get this custom CSS & JS files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the main repository (either directly or via NPM) and then include just the radio JS and CSS in your build. How you go about this depends upon your existing build pipeline for your project.

MDL does not provide component-level resources directly since the need for that isn't great enough and with our color combinations it would lead to an exponential amount of extra files.

Comment: Thanks Garbee. Do you know any other library that will provide component-level resources?

Comment: None do. Any libraries that exist for UX that I have seen only provide full kits. If you want individual ones, they all require you to download and build your own. Bootstrap has a very granular customizer to let you pick and chose what is in your build, but building something like  that is quite intricate.